# How to use login_id value of user factory inside product factory as owner attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using rails 3.0 and factory_girl 1.3. I have 2 factories in my factories.rb file which are as follows:-

```
Factory.define :user do 
    login_id 'Test'
    email 'test@url.com'
    password 'test1234'
end

Factory.define :product do
    sequence(:name) {|n| "product#{n}" }

end
```

Now I have one attribute **owner** in product, which has **validates_presence_of** and **validates_inclusion_of** *User.all* validations inside Product.rb (i.e. Product model). So, if Test is a user we can use Test as valid owner otherwise it will fail. So, my question is How to use owner inside product factory, while running the ProductControllerTest it will be pre populated as a valid owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following link you will found deep digging of your problem and it's solution.

[How do I able to create a user before initialization of model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316019/how-do-i-able-to-create-a-user-before-initialization-of-model)