# How do I able to create a user before initialization of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

In my model(Product) i have a validation, that each product should have a valid owner (login_id of user)

```
validates_presence_of :owner
validates_inclusion_of :owner, :in => User.first.login_id, :message => "%{value} is not a valid owner name"
```

I am trying to create product mock object using factory girl

for creating a new product I need login_id of a user.
to do so i have create a user.

up to this every thing is ok, but when i am trying to create a Product using that user's login_id 
product is not create, and displaying validation message ("User1 is not a valid owner name").

After digging into deeper i found that

1. Problem arise from validation in my model.
2. I have a validation (validates_inclusion_of :owner, :in => User.first.login_id) which initialize before creating the mock user in factory.rb, 
   (up to that time no user is created in database, user is created after initialization of model when it  execute factory.rd )

My question is: 
1. How do I able to create a user before initialization of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem as follows:

In my model I have replaced the 'Rails validation' by writing Custom validation method. This custom validation method will be called at the time of creating 'Product'.

```
validates_presence_of :owner
validate :owner_should_be_registered_user

def owner_should_be_registered_user
    if !User.all_user.include? owner and !owner.nil?
      errors.add(:owner, "is not a valid user")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create a user object, and then pass that object to your product factory? This should create a valid user and then supply it through the owner association and make the product valid.

```
user = Factory(:user, :name => "User1")
product = Factory(:product, :owner => user)
```

This user apparently has to be the first user too? So if you have existing user objects then you can try clearing all users before you create the first one.

```
User.delete_all
```

Comment: This user need not to be first user it can be any of the registered user. If I do as per you I got following error:ArgumentError: Not registered: product
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.0.4/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:15:in `find'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.0.4/lib/factory_girl.rb:42:in `factory_by_name'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.0.4/lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb:53:in `default_strategy'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-2.0.4/lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb:146:in `Factory'